# Content Security Policy conflict

Tags: content-security-policy

I have a problem with setting up a CSP. I have connected the snap.svg.js lib for implementing the animation on my page. This libs make my animation to have a lot of inline styles (to every  in my svg, which are about 2000+). So if I do not specify `'unsafe-inline'` like this:
...
`"style-src 'unsafe-inline'; "`
...
, I will have a lot of violations in console. But I do not want to allow inline styles in the sence of security. How can I allow presenting only that inline styles, which are generated form snap.svg.js lib?
My csp (report only for testing):

```
$csp = "Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: "
   . "default-src 'self' http://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com ; "

   . "font-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com https://fonts.gstatic.com data:  ; "

   . "script-src  'self' 'sha256-4B8QbxkufkPFIEFoveWSoiyIpMLitEc/N9oopV9wrU4=' 'sha256-KoZvlNi6WIlva5SMPsgkZKuz3pwSCUhpugmi7saPqak=' ; "

   . "style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com ; "

   . "img-src 'self' http://1.gravatar.com ; ";
header($csp);
```

Answer (score 0):

With a nonce in CSP 3 you can propagate trust to scripts loaded by other scripts, but I don't believe a *script* nonce has any method to propagate to a *style*.

What you would need to do would either be:

1. Alter the library (eek) to add a nonce to every inline style it adds. You'd also have to have a nonce working for both your CSP and generated pages. This is the best solution but also the hardest to implement.
2. Use SHA hashes for each inline style. This gets messy and impractical fast, but if you only have a few predictable inline styles, it can let you get away without doing a full scale nonce implementation or lessening security.
3. Just use `unsafe-inline`. Obviously not ideal, but better than not using CSP at all as long as Javascript and other active content are locked down. Style is one of the more dangerous ones but doesn't really hold a candle to the danger of `script-src` and probably `object-src`.

Which is best will come down to your situation. I'd try the SHA hash method first and see exactly how many hashes you'll need. If they're totally made on the fly and you've got dozens of them it's probably not going to work out.

It is unfortunately my experience that most third party libs are not made with CSP in mind and are difficult or impossible to get to work with it. It's probably something where until libraries/CDNs/etc are expected to support CSP we're going to keep having headaches.